# Change time formate in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Time object which contains minutes and seconds like "05:37". I like to know a way to convert this to the following formate : "5m 37s".

Comment: I don't know ruby-on-rails, but you should use regular expressions for this.

Comment: [`DateTime#strftime`](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking of of a Time object, this is easy:

```
 t=Time.now
 puts "#{t.min}m #{t.sec}s"
 =>15m 28s
```

If you have a string

```
 s="05:37"
 t=s.split(':').map{|i| i.to_i}
 puts "#{t.first}m #{t.last}s"
 =>5m 37s
```

Or shorter

```
 s.split(':').map{|i| i.to_i}.join("m ")+"s"
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the comment suggesting `strftime`, you could also just use `gsub`:

```
"05:37".gsub(/(\d+):(\d+)/, '\1m \2s')
#=> "05m 37s"
```

If you don't want the leading zero, it's easy enough to get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

```
[your_time_object].strftime('%Mm %Ss').
```

For further detail try [this](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

Answer (score -2):

Nevermind got it:

```
[(total_response_time.to_i / counter_for_response_time.to_i) / 60 % 60, (total_response_time.to_i / counter_for_response_time.to_i) % 60].map { |t| t.to_s.rjust(2,'0') }.join('m ')
```

For anyone who want to convert it like this in future.

Comment: That's not the same thing than in your question.  What are total_response_time, counter_response_time?

Comment: and a much cleaner way to achieve it:

    (total_response_time.to_i / counter_for_response_time.to_i).tap{|t| s="#{t/60}m #{t%60}s"}
    puts s

Comment: This doesn't look like a nice way to do **anything**, it looks really confusing and complicated.  If you have a Time object then just use strftime on it as people have said.